# dealing with asynchronous updating of an object

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

```
const globalObject = {};
const varAList = [.....];
const varBList = [.....];
const varA = await Promise.all(
    varAList.map(
        async (aObject) => {
            const toReturn = [];
            for (const bObject of varBList) {
                if (!globalObject[bObject.id]) {
                    console.log(`getting ${bObject.id}`);
                    globalObject[bObject.id] = await getObject(bObject.id);
                }
                if (globalObject[bObject.id].important == true){
                    toReturn.push(globalObject[bObject.id].something)
                }
            }
            return {aObject.id: toReturn}
        }
    )
);
```

The problem with this code is that the line ``` console.log(``getting ${bObject.id}``) ``` will be repeated for the same id since the `varAList` is going in parallel. How do I make sure that I am asynchronously checking this object and not remaking a request if it already exists?
Any solutions?

Comment: why don't you try making getObject call as async? let the map callback remain a sync func

Comment: The posted code seems to have been cut down too far - the `aObject` parameter of the `.map` function argument isn't used. Apart from that, try populating `globalObject` before iterating over the `varAList` array - which can probably be done synchronously,

Comment: @advayrajhansa sorry i dont follow
your saying that i remove the await from `getObject`?

Comment: @traktor populating `globalObject` before i iterate over `varAList` kind of beats the purpose of this question. Cause I still dont know what goes into the `globalObject` unless I iterate through `varAList`

Comment: made some changes @traktor

Comment: The changes don't compile: `{aObject.id: toReturn}` is not valid. Even if did, the rest of the loop is producing a `toReturn` array with the same values in each loop iteration. Please include, in the question, what the code is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You question is confusing, If understand your correctly, You don't want to iterate over `varAList`?

```js
const globalObject = {};
const varAList = [.....];
const varBList = [.....];

async function* genarateResult() {
    for (const bObject of varBList) {
        let aObject = varAList.shift();
        let obj = globalObject[bObject.id];
        let toReturn = [];
        if (!obj) {
            console.log(`getting ${bObject.id}`);
            globalObject[bObject.id] = await getObject(bObject.id);
        }
        if (obj.important == true) {
            toReturn.push(obj.something)
        }
        yield { [aObject.id]: toReturn };
    }
}

for await (const val of genarateResult()) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

Does it answer you question? or what I missed?

Comment: Does we should iterate over `varBList`  or `varAList` ? In my answer I  iterate over `varBList`, is that correct?

Comment: @Bergi , thanks , to point out!, I will update my answer later...

Comment: my question was when I use map and have awaits within the map, a reference to the globalObject kind of gets finicky, like on each iteration or `varAList`, even if i may have updated globalObject previously, i still fail to verify if that iteration was done before, since its async.

Comment: @Sakibul Alam, can you show as an example? that illustrate your problem